# Where can I see the file in path getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the below code to create a file in android as

```
    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "content.txt");
```

I want to open the file in my phone. I went to the path

`Local storage/Android/data/<my package>/files/`

However, I cannot see the file. My Android version is 5.0.1. What is happen? One more thing, Do you think the above way is a good way to save file? What is common path to save a file in Android? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file locates in `/data/data/[your package]/files`,it's app private directory.

It's a good way or not depends on the purpose of your file.

1. if you want your file visable only to you(the app developer),the folder is right
2. if the file can be visable to others and the file is large,then you can put it to `sdcard` folder
3. if you want the file stay even if your app being removed,you shouldn't put it in this folder.Because when an app removed,the all data in `/data/data/[package name]/` will be deleted also.

Comment: How can I open the private directory? I cannot see the path in my phone. Do I need turn on something?

Comment: @user3051460  Only your device is root,you can see the private folder.

Comment: Thanks. If I use android studio. Could I see it in DDMS?

Comment: @user3051460,Unfortunatly,we can't.but you can see these by `adb` command.

Comment: @user3051460,sorry,although we can't see filesystem of device in android-studio directly,,but you can click `monitor` icon to open device monitor,you can see all visiable files there.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will save that file in ExternalStorageDirectory for debug. After that, I wiil change to internal

Answer (score 1):

You find in:

/data/data/[your package name]/files/